# HTML/CSS Logo with Text

Tags: html, css, text

So I was trying achieve [this logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsBAs.jpg) but the text wont go in middle.

I have tried vertical align and line-height but no luck. Hope someone helps :)

Code:

```
<div>
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"><div id=""></div></a>
        <p>title<br>
        text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {height: 100px; background: #fff}
#logo div {background: url(/img/logo.png) center/contain no-repeat; width: 70px; height: 70px; float: left}
#logo p {vertical-align: middle}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css on the container element

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: ...on the container element, should be added

Comment: thank you this one does it. im new to web designing  :)

Comment: happy to help, note that older browsers do not support display: flex. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're using html and css, just make sure that both the text and the image are in the same div.

You can also follow this tutorial if that can make it easier: https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works .
simple example

```
<div>
  <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <span >verticle text.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods.

One of them is:

```
#parent {display: table;}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with text:

```
transform: translate(12px, 76px); //adjust it to fit your needs
```

Comment: thanks. this works but i need to change the values whenever I edit the text right? Can i have it automatically in the middle?

Comment: Yes change values X, Y to put it in the middle, or where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Well flexbox is the easiest way to go around

```
<div id='foo'>
 <div id='logo'><img src='path.png'></div>
 <div id='text'>Title HEre</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#foo {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
}
```